# Electron NodeJS Ag-Grid Cannot Import

Tags: node.js, electron, ag-grid

In render.js I have

```
import { Grid } from 'ag-grid-community';
import { tableMethods } from './table.js';
```

I created my own custom table methods and decided to try ag-grid since mine aren't as fast as theirs (no surprise).  Unfortunately, while I could get my own methods loading from my js file by setting

```
<script type="module" src="render.js"></script>
```

I cannot get ag-grid to load, I get this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "ag-grid-community". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".
```

I used npm i ag-grid-community -D to install it. I wasn't sure if I needed the -D, so I tried without that and it still shows same error.

*Note - of course I've tried doing what the error message says.  But it didn't resolve and the documentation doesn't mention anything about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this working by adding following before my render.js file

```
<script src="ag-grid-community.js"></script>
```

I also disabled type=module once I realized this is probably the intended way to split up rendering scripts, or at least that was my guess.